# Creation of Menu items in QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis

I've got some code which adds menu items with some inactive by default. They only become active when the reverse item (to open the data) above it are triggered.

I am now looking at using a loop to do this rather than having to repeat the code for each change in value.

It's mostly working fine, except for enabling/disabling the menu items.

CODE that is in the loop

```
                        elif i == 2:
                            a = QAction(row[i], self.iface.mainWindow())# add the last level of menu item
                            a.setObjectName(row[i]) # Assign the name
                            a.triggered.connect(self.loadLayer) # load the layer(s)
                            actions.append(a)
                            submenu.addAction(a)
    #add close option and seperator
                            msg = 'Close '+row[i]
                            cls = QAction(msg, self.iface.mainWindow())
                            cls.setObjectName(msg)
                            cls.triggered.connect(self.unloadLayer) # unload the layer(s`)
```

self.cls.setEnabled(False) # I tried this but get an error

```
                            actions.append(cls) #?
                            submenu.addAction(cls) #?
                            submenu.addSeparator()#?
```

What execatly do these do?

```
    #end
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

CODE that is not in the loop but works as expected

```
    menuSewerageNetwork = QMenu('Sewerage Network', self.menuInfrastructure)
    self.actionOpenSewerageActive = QAction('Open Sewerage Active', self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.actionOpenSewerageAll = QAction('Open Sewerage All', self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.actionCloseSewerageActive = QAction('Close Sewerage Active', self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.actionCloseSewerageAll = QAction('Close Sewerage All', self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.actionCloseSewerageActive.setEnabled(False)
    self.actionCloseSewerageAll.setEnabled(False)

    menuSewerageNetwork.addAction(self.actionOpenSewerageActive)
    menuSewerageNetwork.addAction(self.actionOpenSewerageAll)
    menuSewerageNetwork.addSeparator()
    menuSewerageNetwork.addAction(self.actionCloseSewerageActive)
    menuSewerageNetwork.addAction(self.actionCloseSewerageAll)

    self.menuInfrastructure.addMenu(menuSewerageNetwork)

    self.actionOpenSewerageActive.triggered.connect(self.openSewerageAll)
    self.actionCloseSewerageActive.triggered.connect(self.closeSewerageAll)
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question,remove unnecesarry lines and put the error code!maybe you need use lambda functions in your loop

Comment: I thought having the example working code would be useful. The error is AttributeError: 'Menus_from_CSV' object has no attribute 'cls'